# Paths and shapes: how to implement those?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, vector-graphics

I have seen that Visual Studio Blend, Photoshop and Illustrator has some nice path and shape tools. I have also seen that - unfortunately - those are missing from Unity Engine. While there are some expensive assets on Unity Store to get around this, I don't even need that complicated pack (and I couldn't afford it right now) so I plan to implement my basic shape and path drawing kit for Unity. The thing is though that I have no clue where to start. 
Could someone experienced show me some material to start from? When googling this all I saw was "how to use the path tool in this and that." 
As Unity uses c# maybe I should use that language but I learn any that is necessary.

**Edit:**

Got a "close because unclear what I want". What I would like as answer is some materials, tutorials, articles on programming these path and shape tools as I was unable to find them on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you need is 'mesh generation'. It is possible to do this yourself quite simply. All you need to do is specify a list of points and triangles and set those on a mesh to create a mesh dynamically.

This is an in depth topic but it is quite easy to get up and running quickly. This approach is fast enough to use on mobile as well, as long as objects are not too complex.

For speed optimization - it is the setting of vertices and triangles on a mesh which is slow. Once they are set the object is the same as a standard mesh, and will render quickly.

Here are some resources on mesh generation:

https://nrj.io/procedural-curved-mesh-generation-in-unity-part-1/

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/

Comment: Thanks, that isn't a bad idea either. I plan to generate those meshes prior to runtime as in the particular project I use only silhouette textures with binary alpha (fully opaque or fully transp). and then assign an unlit single colour material.

Comment: I see, depending what you want it is also possible to use a texture based approach. You can use 'Render Textures' in Unity for this - here's an example: http://gatemedia.ch/software/2016/01/29/high-performance-real-time-painting-in-unity.html

Comment: I filling my bookmarks with those :D How come I haven't seen those solutions??

Comment: As you use Unity more and more you will get used to all the nuances of it I'm sure : ) It's actually possible to do very powerful and dynamic graphic stuff even on mobile. Another powerful area is the use of shaders - even for 2D games. Something like this: https://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=48508.msg1163762#msg1163762

Comment: Sir/Madam, you are full of links :D I'm comfortable with Unity's scripting, but I have never did anything more than using my pre-made sprites. High time I learned those. Any more useful links? Even on a separate answer so I can upvote again? These stuff are what I always wanted to use but never got far with them.

Comment: Nice, I'm not sure how many more specific links I have - I would recommend just doing some projects using more graphics oriented stuff and you will be familiar with it in no time. Unity forums is a good resource too if you to ask any questions, as the community is very helpful. As far as cool things to make you can look at games made with Unity for whatever platform you are targeting and look at cool stuff they have done and try to re-create. After you are familiar you can move on to doing you own effects : D